# RWEP in Event Receiver Item Added

Tags: event-receivers, runwithelevatedprivileges

Any idea why the follow code is not working in item added?

Error:

`<nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Access denied.`

The code:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://portal.xyz.com);
Guid siteId = site.ID;
SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
Guid webId = web.ID;

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite osite = new SPSite(siteId))
    {
        using (SPWeb oweb = osite.OpenWeb(webId))
        {
            properties.ListItem.File.CopyTo(properties.Web.Site.Url + "/SecretDL/" + properties.ListItem.File.Name);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: try using SPSite site = properties.Web.Site, SPWeb web = properties.Web instead of initializing objects as in above example.

Comment: SPSite site = properties.Web.Site;
            Guid siteId = site.ID;
            SPWeb web = properties.Web;
            Guid webId = web.ID; File didn't copy.

Comment: 0x80070005Access denied

Comment: are you having access on that sharepoint list. On which your are writing code? I mean what rights are you having

Comment: Yes. The test account has full access to the list with the event receiver running the RWEP code for item added.

Comment: try using properties.ListItem.CopyTo(
      properties.WebUrl + "/Destination/" + properties.ListItem.File.Name);

Comment: are you trying to copy the list item to another sharepoint list on item added event then please check the links, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059175/copy-files-to-document-library-in-sharepoint

Comment: Similarly, this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565200/how-to-copy-newly-added-document-with-metadata-to-another-document-library and this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075323/copy-list-items-from-one-list-to-another-in-sharepoint/1075343#1075343

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36353/discussion-between-niranjan-kulkarni-and-bswee).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elevated list item is the answer. List item needs to be elevated in the RWEP block to avoid the access denied problem.

```
 SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
            {
                using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb(properties.Web.ID))
                {
                    SPList elevatedList = elevatedWeb.Lists[currentItem.ParentList.ID];
                    SPListItem elevatedListItem = elevatedList.GetItemById(currentItem.ID);
                    elevatedListItem.File.CopyTo(elevatedWeb.Site.Url + "/SecretDL/" + elevatedListItem.File.Name);       
                }                                                     
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a spsite object with osite name inside RWEP

```
using (SPSite osite = new SPSite(siteId))
```

and used "site" name for opening web!

```
using (SPWeb oweb = site.OpenWeb(webId))
```

you should be using

```
using (SPWeb oweb = osite.OpenWeb(webId))
```

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed that and it still doesn't work